# Closure as parameter in Thread

Tags: multithreading, groovy, closures

Why this code doesn't work (no output)?

```
clo1 = {
    for(int i =0; i<=10; i++){
        println(i);
    }
}

def thread = Thread.start { clo1 }
```

But this do work:

```
def thread = Thread.start {
    for(int i =0; i<=10; i++){
        println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, but I have to choose the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute `clo1` in the thread you can either do

```
Thread.start clo1 // same as Thread.start(clo1)
```

or

```
Thread.start { clo1() }
```

The first one passes the closure directly to `Thread.start`. The second solution creates a new closure which executes `clo1`.

With `Thread.start { clo1 }` just you pass a new closure (that does nothing) to `Thread.start`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you placed a closure(clo1) inside the closure passed to Thread.start { clo1 }. Calling Threat.start clo1 will give you the result that you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're wrapping a closure in a closure

Try

```
def thread = Thread.start clo1
```